# Symfony2 using a "global function" inside a form without overkill

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I know I can do a lot of stuff...but I'd like to avoid overkill.

I have a class with general util methods. I want to be able to call one of those methods from inside a formType.

What I did is the following:

Inside the formType I added

```
use AppBundle\Util\GeneralUtil;

class HRMgmtFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(GeneralUtil $util)
    {
        $this->util = $util;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $timeCommitment = $this->util->generatePercentVectorByStep(1);

    ...all the rest of the stuff
```

And when I call it from the controller I have:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new HRMgmtFormType(new GeneralUtil()), array(...all the stuff I need here...);
```

It works.

Is this ok/elegant?

I basically avoided declaring my general util class as a service, and most important declaring my form as a service (and injecting the generalUtil service inside).

Thank you!

SN

Comment: why you can't instantiate it in the form?

Comment: @Matteo It gave me an error...

Comment: What exactly is overkill?  Once something is dead then can it get any deader?  Follow @Evgeniy Kuzmin suggestion and learn the basics of services.  Once you understand the process then you can make an intelligent decision as to which approach to use.  By the way, while instantiating the object inside the form is not recommended, there is no reason it should not work for the posted code.  You should also take the time to understand the error.

Comment: The overkill is the hassle of declaring the form as service, but considering that for other issues I need it to be declared as service, then let service be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you have the class "GeneralUtil" such simple as you have it now: without any dependencies and any configuration parameters, your solution is fair. But there are some more aspects that you should think about:

1. Will be "GeneralUtil" reusable at other places?
2. Will you need to make unit tests? if so, do you plan to mock the util if you plan to get "pure" unit test and make dependency injection(DI) with mock?
3. Do you plan extend the util's functionality? will it get some dependencies or configuration in future?

If yes, then  it is better to get the benefit from Symfony SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) approach and refactor your code to SOA and DI, that will allow you follow another important patter as DRY (Don't repeat yourself) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

**Update to your commet:**

So you can see from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services

> Defining your form type as a service is a good practice and makes it
>   really easy to use in your application.

but as I already explained about the utils class, similar logic is about forms. So if you plan to reuse your form, then you can do it as service, but if you will have several different forms that will use your utils class, then it's better leave the form as class, but make a service for the utils. In addition you can do it if you see possibility to overwrite your form some other i.e 3rd party forms.

So benefits list from form as service:

- in case of multiply usage, it initialized only once
- easy to overwrite by other form
- globally configured from parameters ans DI other services

Comment: Ok, so maybe it's worthwile to define the form as a service and inject this new class (also as a service)...right?